# Add a title field in magento product image

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have followed [this : Adding an extra text area in product images tab backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/132019/28348) post to add text field, Now field is showing but i am not getting the value in observer. Here is data :

```
2017-01-31T06:02:06+00:00 DEBUG (7): Array
(
    [images] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [value_id] => 2347
                    [file] => /b/h/bh_tread.jpg
                    [product_id] => 1673
                    [label] => BH Fitness S7Ti Treadmill
                    [position] => 1
                    [title] => 
                    [disabled] => 0
                    [label_default] => BH Fitness S7Ti Treadmill
                    [position_default] => 1
                    [title_default] => 
                    [disabled_default] => 0
                    [url] => http://localhost/gym/media/catalog/product/b/h/bh_tread.jpg
                    [removed] => 0
                )

                   )

    [values] => {"image":"\/b\/h\/bh_tread.jpg","small_image":"\/b\/h\/bh_tread.jpg","thumbnail":"\/b\/h\/bh_tread.jpg"}
)
```

I want add a text field in image section same as **Label** field as shown in below pic.

I have added the following code in gallery.phtml

```
 <td class="cell-label"><input type="text" <?php if($_block->getElement()->getReadonly()):?> disabled="disabled"<?php endif;?> class="input-text" onkeyup="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" onchange="<?php echo $_block->getJsObjectName(); ?>.updateImage('__file__')" /></td>
```

[image]

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965237/add-new-image-attribute-in-magento-backend-and-get-all-images-of-that-new-image

Comment: I have tried it but they are radio type i need text filed instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an extra text area in product images tab backend](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93600/adding-an-extra-text-area-in-product-images-tab-backend)

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara I have mentioned same post in my post did you see that ? That solution not working

Answer (score 1):

For more info please go here:
http://sarathlal.com/create-and-use-custom-image-attribute-in-magento/

EDIT:

I see.
It should works:
[Adding an extra text area in product images tab backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/93600/adding-an-extra-text-area-in-product-images-tab-backend)

Comment: I have tried it but they are radio type i need text filed instead

Comment: let me try this one

Comment: is it working fine?

Comment: I working on it, once it will be completed, I will accept your answer thanks for your support

Comment: I see. Good luck ;)